# How to import products to UberCart 3 using CSV data?

Tags: drupal, module, feed, ubercart

I am using D7 and UC3, and I try to import many products at a time using CSV data via Feeds module. The problem is that Feeds hasn't *Product information* fields (like SKU, price etc.) in target column, so that I can't upload all that necessary data. So, is there any way to access those fields from product information via Feeds (or otherwise). Thanks in advance!

That's the data I can't upload via Feeds:

[image: That's the data I can't upload via Feeds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Found a module for D7 that adds all the UberCart attributes in the list:

http://drupal.org/node/1187096

Answer (score 3):

download the zip file and extract to your module folder from below url:
https://drupal.org/node/1802908

for help go through: 
http://drupal.org/node/1797778